# Looking to calculate expected profit from sale of house

Tags: taxes, canada, real-estate, rental-property, ontario

I'm trying to calculate the money I will see as profit from the sale of my house.

I'm tallying the various expenses associated with selling and would like input on any costs I'm missing. I'm in Ontario, Canada and not moving to another house (need to apartment surf for the next few years due to work).

Here are **estimates** I have so far. What costs might I be missing?


Remaining mortgage balance: -$305,000

Sale price of house: +$360,000

Early payout penalty to mortgage company: -$2,300

Lawyers fees: -$2,000.00?

Capital gains tax and other taxes: -?

Realtors fees (but hoping to sell privately/comfree/grapevine): 0 to -$18,000 (5% sale price)

Unforeseen repairs: -?


This totals +$50,600 "in my pocket" minus taxes and assuming no realtor fees. Am I way off base? Is there anything that can be done to minimize the tax hit?

Comment: You base you profit on what price you bought the house for not the balance of the mortgage. Plus you have not included buying costs (eg. conveyancing, title searches, stamp duties, and any other taxes).

Comment: Ignore any costs associated with initial purchase and any mortgage paydown (it's a rental)

Comment: No you do not ignore cost associated with initial purchase, you include them (you have not). If you are trying to work out any capital gains for tax purposes, them mortgage paydown has nothing to do with it, but buying and selling costs reduce your capital gains.

Answer (score -1):

Costs you may have to pay include:

- legal fees for services, including a statement of adjustment (buyer reimburses you for prepaid property taxes past the sale date)
- bank prepayment charges
- registration fees
- mortgage prepayment penalty and  discharge fees
- realtor or real estate agent fees
- sales tax depending on where you live
- capital gains tax for an income property
- structural repairs

Comment: I wonder why this got downvoted. seems like a decent answer.

Comment: Downvoting is part of the process on Stack.  No biggie.  The irritating thing is when people do it but do not comment on what's wrong with a question or an  answer nor do they take the time to provide a better answer.

Comment: I'm not sure why it got downvoted. Probably because most of this answer I already have in the question. Some new things here though, such as registration and bank prepayment charges (neither of which I am familiar with) - Bob, can you elaborate on what these two entail?